# Pinging Multiple servers using Python with PyCharm IDE

Tags: python, server, ping

I tried pinging multiple servers using hostname, without extra .txt file.
I'm trying like this..

```
import os
for i in range(1,2): #`for i in range(1,2):
   hostname1= "google.con"  # example
   hostname2 = "google.com"  # example
response = os.system("ping -n 1 " + hostname1)
response = os.system("ping -n 1 " + hostname2)
```

and then check the response...

```
if response == 0:
    flag = 'OK'
else:
    flag = 'KO'
if flag == 'OK':
    print('all hosts are up!')
else:
    print('something is wrong')
```

I'm new to Python and PyCharm.

- Please, correct me, in case of any fundamental mistakes.

NKalyan

Comment: insteaf of `hostname1`, `hostname2` you should use list `hostnames = ["google.con", "google.com"]` and later `for host in hostnames:`

Comment: you can't keep two result in one `response` - you should first run first host and check it result and later run second host and check its result. And if you will keep host on list and use `for`-loop then you will have it even simpler

Comment: Why are you intiating the hostnames in a loop? A loop in range(1,2) will be executed only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code makes no sense. Especially your `for`-loop

You should keep hosts on list and use `for`-loop to work with every host separatelly.

You can't assign `response` many times because it will remove previous value and you will check only last result.

```
import os

# --- before loop ---    

hostnames = ["google.con", "google.com", "stackoverflow.com"]

all_ok = True  # at start I assume that all hosts are OK

# --- loop ---

for host in hostnames:
    response = os.system("ping -n 1 " + host)
    if response != 0:
        all_ok = False  # one of host is down
    # don't use `else: all_ok = True` 

# --- after loop ---

if all_ok:
    print('all hosts are up!')
else:
    print('something is wrong')
```

Similar way you can count hosts with problems

```
import os

# --- before loop ---

hostnames = ["google.con", "google.com", "stackoverflow.com"]

count = 0

# --- loop ---

for host in hostnames:
    response = os.system("ping -n 1 " + host)
    if response != 0:
        count += 1  # one of host is down

# --- after loop ---

if count == 0:
    print('all hosts are up!')
else:
    print('number of down hosts:', count)
```

or you can use list for hosts with problems

```
import os

# --- before loop ---

hostnames = ["google.con", "google.com", "stackoverflow.com"]

problems = []  # hosts with problems

# --- loop ---

for host in hostnames:
    response = os.system("ping -n 1 " + host)
    if response != 0:
        problems.append(host)  # one of host is down

# --- after loop ---

if not problems:  # if len(problems) == 0:
    print('all hosts are up!')
else:
    print('number of downed hosts:', len(problems))
    print('hosts:', problems)
```

Comment: Thank you Furas, for your detailed stuff. Thanks a lot.